# JavaScript image rotate permanently

Tags: javascript, canvas, rotation

I’m looking  for a way to rotate an image locally in the browser and store it locally.

I tried to rotate the image with canvas and jQuery rotate. But in boot methods the image is only rotated in the view. As soon as I store these image (e.g. canvas. toDataURL()) I'm getting the original file / rotation.

Is there a way to rotate the image locally in the browser without php/server side interaction?

Thanks!

```
$("#Img").rotate(90);
var dataURL5 = document.getElementById('Img').src;
```

--> `dataURL5` doesn't contain the rotated image but the original... in the browser I have the rotated view....

Or with canvas:

```
context_tmp.translate(canvas_tmp.width , canvas_tmp.height /canvas_tmp.width );
context_tmp.rotate((Math.PI/2));
```

canvas is not a requiredment... i only tried it...

in boot

Comment: What is the question? You are rotating it locally but it doesn't work locally?

Comment: Yes. There is. What have you tried?

Comment: Why even use a canvas? CSS3 `rotate` is all you need

Comment: It renders the rotation, but wen i try to store the picture from the element (document.getElementById('Img').src)  the rotation is not in the jpeg data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the image from the canvas using its [`toDataURL()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement) method.

You cannot extract any image data from `src` property (but the original URL).

Note: If the original image is from different *origin* than the page this won't work as CORS kicks in ([cross-origin resource sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)). This is by design and intent.

You need to `rotate` and `translate` the canvas using its context, then draw the image. Now you can call `toDataURL()` to get the image data (image will be blank if CORS kicked in).

**Example**:

```
/// translate so rotation happens at center of image
ctx.translate(image.width * 0.5, image.height * 0.5);

/// rotate canvas context
ctx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI); /// 90deg clock-wise

/// translate back so next draw op happens in upper left corner
ctx.translate(-image.width * 0.5, -image.height * 0.5);

/// image will now be drawn rotated
ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

/// get the rotated image (unless CORS kicks in...)
var dataUri = canvas.toDataURL();
```

I made a fiddle with this code but as CORS is effective for the image I am using it is kind of pointless, but anyways - [**here goes**](http://jsfiddle.net/AbdiasSoftware/G9mMB/).