# Rotate photos based on Original rotation

Tags: javascript, html, rotation, html5-canvas, exif

I'm trying to rotate photos based on their original rotation, as set by the camera in EXIF image data. The trick is that all this should happen in the browser, using JavaScript and HTML5 "canvas".

Currently I'm able to get the rotation of the image but can't rotate the image in case it is inverted or flipped.

**JS code**..

```
   function getOrientation(file, callback) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = function(e) {

var view = new DataView(e.target.result);
if (view.getUint16(0, false) != 0xFFD8) return callback(-2);
var length = view.byteLength, offset = 2;
while (offset < length) {
  var marker = view.getUint16(offset, false);
  offset += 2;
  if (marker == 0xFFE1) {
    if (view.getUint32(offset += 2, false) != 0x45786966) return callback(-1);
    var little = view.getUint16(offset += 6, false) == 0x4949;
    offset += view.getUint32(offset + 4, little);
    var tags = view.getUint16(offset, little);
    offset += 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < tags; i++)
      if (view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12), little) == 0x0112)
        return callback(view.getUint16(offset + (i * 12) + 8, little));
  }
  else if ((marker & 0xFF00) != 0xFF00) break;
  else offset += view.getUint16(offset, false);
}
return callback(-1);
 };
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice(0, 64 * 1024));
}


    canvasCtx = document.getElementById("panel").getContext("2d");

        document.getElementById("ifile").onchange = function(event) {

            getOrientation(document.getElementById("ifile").files[0], function(orientation) {
            alert('orientation: ' + orientation);
            });

            this.imageFile = event.target.files[0];

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload =  function(event) {
                var img = new Image();
                //img.style.width = "300px";
                //img.style.height = "300px";

                img.onload = function() {
                    drawImage(img);
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageFile);
        }

        drawImage = function(img) {
            this.canvasCtx.canvas.width = 300;//img.width;
            this.canvasCtx.canvas.height = 300;//img.height;

            if(img.width>img.height){                                               //Landscape Image 
                canvasCtx.width = 300;
                canvasCtx.height = 300 / img.width * img.height;
            } else {                                                                  //Portrait Image
                canvasCtx.width = 300 / img.height * img.width;
                canvasCtx.height = 300;
            } 

            canvasCtx.translate(img.width * 0.5, img.height * 0.5);
            /// rotate canvas context
            canvasCtx.rotate(0.5 * Math.PI); /// 90deg clock-wise

            /// translate back so next draw op happens in upper left corner
            canvasCtx.translate(-img.width * 0.5, -img.height * 0.5);

            this.canvasCtx.drawImage(img,0,0,canvasCtx.width, canvasCtx.height);
            url = canvasCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
        }
```

I have 2 photos taken form ios, android having orientation as 3 and 6 respectively. I would like to change their orientation to 1. Can't figure how to do that.Please help..

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18339043/javascript-image-rotate-permanently/18344171#18344171 you would need to first translate to center of rotation, rotate, translate back and then draw image. For handling sizes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26768866/image-rotate-resize-canvas-based-on-image-height-and-width/26783251#26783251

Comment: And just in case, after drawing the image to canvas all meta-data such as exif is lost when you save out the new rotated image.

Comment: @K3N I have edited my code above as specified in the 1st link but still no improvement..any idea what I'm doing wrong??